Reference request for a formula in representation theory
The following is stated without proof in [1], what is a good resource to learn about it?
Theorem. Let $G$ be a finite group, $g\in G$, and $k\ge 0$. Then $|G|^{2k-1}\sum (\dim V)^{1-2k}\chi_V(g)=|\{(x_1,y_1,\dots,x_k,y_k)\in G^{2k}:[x_1,y_1]\dots[x_k,y_k]=g\}|$
the sum being over all irreducible representations $V$ of $G$.
[1] Relative Frobenius Formula, A. Aizenbud, N. Avni, Y. Krauz https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~aizenr/4Publications/Rel_Frob.pdf

This looks like the generator count formulas that arise from class multiplication coefficients. See e.g. section 2.5 in Lux/Pahlings: Representation Theory, A Computational Approach

In the special case $g = e$ this is known as Mednykh's formula and can be proven using 2d Dijkgraaf-Witten theory; see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703073. I don't know if that argument generalizes to this case.

The special case $k=1$ appears in Isaacs' Character Theory of Finite Groups as exercise 3.10.

For $k = 1$ the formula is very well known and attributed to Frobenius. As mentioned in the comments, there are exercises in the character theory book by Isaacs (Exercises 3.9, 3.10 there) giving hints for this case.
In general see for example Lemma 9.1 of the following paper [*].
[*] A. Shalev, Word maps, conjugacy classes, and a noncommutative Waring-type theorem. Ann. of Math. (2) 170 (2009), no. 3, 1383--1416. https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v170-n3-p08-p.pdf

A nice exposition can also be found in the reference below. The statement is part of Theorem 1.
T. Tambour, The number of solutions of some equations in finite groups and a new proof of Itô’s theorem, Commun. Algebra 28, No. 11, 5353-5361 (2000). https://www2.math.su.se/reports/1998/15/1998-15.pdf
